# Backup of ArcSDE version

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

Is there any way how to backup particular version in ArcSDE geodatabase?

I want to delete some versions from our geodatabase, but it would be great if I can create backup first and restore version if it will be needed.

Comment: Versioning doesn't work like that. It you delete a version, the only way to recover is to restore the entire point-in-time database backup you made before deletion. I recommend you spend some time with the documentation and free training classes, to better understand the optimistic locking paradigm. The TLDR snapshot is that versions take almost no space at all, while the state tree uses only the space it needs to.

Comment: Hi Vince. I asked because I saw article where this backup/restore of version was done. So it is possible. It should be just restoring delta tables and state tables. But seems that it is not just easy.

Comment: Let me put it this way: I'm an Esri subject matter expert on enterprise geodatabases, and I wouldn't consider attempting a partial versioning restore without a pressing reason, several complete backups, hundreds of hours of project budget available, and a document from the customer acknowledging that the attempt was likely to destroy the existing database, and all work subsequent to that might be lost.

Comment: I see. I remeber that it was something with some custom tables and functionality for tracking every edits. But as you wrote not possible with ordinary tools. Thanks for comments and clarification

Comment: Before deleting versions, I would export out the most actively/recently edited file(s) to a file geodatabase and confirm with my DBA that we have a good backup of the whole database. It is a hassle to restore either way. If the problem is people leaving edits unreconciled or unposted or other organizational issues, you could look at Archiving snapshots and Edit Tracking options to better track database changes.